# Android 7.x Deletes /data/user/0/com.myappid/files/ after taskbar exit / reload

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, android-7.1-nougat

This only seems to be an issue on Android 7.x+ I am copying a pre-populated database file (SQLite) to /data/user/0/com.myappid/files/MYDB.db I am using this method to extract and copy:

First, this is a part of a static class which fires from MainActivity.

```
public static string filename { get; set; }

private static string dbPath
{
    get
    {
        return Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), filename);
    }
}

private static SQLiteConnection dbConn;

private static bool current {get; set;}

public static string GetLocalFilePath()
        {
            if (!current)
            {
                if (!CheckdbVersion())
                {
                    DeleteFileIfExists();
                }
            }
            CopyDatabaseIfNotExists();

            return dbPath;
        }

private static bool CheckdbVersion()
    {
        if(dboConn == null)
        dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);

        try
        {
            string sqltxt = "SELECT Version FROM dbVersion;";

            var result = dbConn.ExecuteScalar<string>(sqltxt);

            if (result == dbVersion)
            {
                current = true;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message.Contains("no such table"))
            {
                current = false;
            }
            else throw ex;
        }
        return current;
    }




    private static void CopyDatabaseIfNotExists()
    {
            if (!File.Exists(dbPath))
            {
                using (var br = new BinaryReader(Application.Context.Assets.Open("MYDB.db")))
                {
                    using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(dbPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)))
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                        int length = 0;
                        while ((length = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            bw.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

EDIT - Root question:

Why is SQLite saying "no such table" when this happens and the select sql is executed for the second time, but only on 7.x+? At first I thought the file was being deleted (because "no such table" is a default error in SQLite). But, it turns out that my static SQLiteConnection class is / was causing all of theses issues on 7.x only.

Comment: How do you get the dbpath? I'd suggest to try using `dbPath = context.getDatabasePath(database).getPath();`, if you want to store the database in the usual/default path (where database would equate to "MYDB.db"). This would equate to `/date/data/com.myappid/databases/MYDB,db` or `/data/user/0/com.myappid/databases/MYDB.db` (the same location, just later version appear to use `user/0` instead of `data`).

Comment: @MikeT That's a good suggestion! However, that is not the root of the issue. It turns out, I am wiping my own database due to a completely different issue which is how different versions of android handle the back button / retain the app lifecycle (I think). Standby... editing.

Comment: You could get an empty database i.e no user tables if the copy failed, say for permissions, as the openOrCreate (when you try to open the database) would create an empty database. If this is the case, try doing a Select * from sqlite_master, if that works then the database is there, if you look at the returned rows and your tables aren't there then this could be the issue. Perhaps back button is causing the activity's onCreate to fire the asset copy again and thus the error and thus the empty DB.

Comment: @MikeT I am basically doing that. I store a dbVersion table with a version number in there and compare it to a static value retrieved from resources. If the versions don't match or if the dbVersion table doesn't exist, it will re-copy the file. That is what's happening everytime the user presses the back button in Nougat - the MainActivity fires and the everytime it says the dbVersion table doesn't exist, so I recopy. What's odd, is that if you completely close the app and re-open, it stops happening. It's as if, Nougat won't persist the file until the app is closed?

Comment: Uhhm, not sure how you opening DB (never used xamarin) normal android (SQLiteOpenhelper) will set the DBVersion. If not you try setting it, when you have opend the DB, using `PRAGMA user_version = integer`

Comment: @MikeT Added code showing how I open the db. Not sure what you mean about setting the DBVersion? dbVersion is a custom table I created where I stash the version in a prepopulated db. This allows me to force a db file overwrite when someone updates the apk from the app store. At some point in the future instead of doing a simple overwrite, i'll have to do a merge and update the version, as I am allowing some user settings to be stored in the db as well now. PS: Thank you for the assistance - AGAIN! :) You and SushiHangover.

Comment: SQLITE database has a user_version field, normal(sic) android (non xamarin etc) uses that for calling onUpgrade and onDownGrade methods intended for managing schema versions. However, you could prehaps utilise, the version number using the above to set it and without `= integer` to retrieve it. [uer_version](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version). However, crossed wires saw dbversion which is what the user_version is frequently called.

Comment: Things I'd do (in principle) get count of bytes written in the copy and write that out to the log, perhaps number of buffers used. i.e. see if it's copying the file in it's entirety. Then immediately after copy do `SELECT * from sqlite_master` and write the rows to the log to see if the copied DB has the tables. In `GetLocalFilePath()` log value of **current** or log inside if's (my guess is that it's this value that's getting messed up).

Comment: @MikeT That all makes sense. I have to know / understand what is going on here that is so different with Nougat. I did resolve the issue by setting the static "current" to true after the copy/filestream. Since it's a static class/property, it remains true until the app is closed and magically, completely closing the app for some reason (on Nougat only) means the file stays where I am expecting it. All that aside, I will do as you suggested and update the question - I have to know why this occurs even if the issue is more or less resolved.

Comment: @MikeT Did the things you'd do "in principle" today. Thank you! Got me to the root of the issue and it turns out the file wasn't being magically deleted. The issue had to do with my use of a static SQLiteConnection object that I'm leaving open while the app is running. The lifecyle in 7.x is somewhat different, and this causes a disconnected / stale connection. The error I was getting "no such table", which I thought meant the file was deleted, actually can mean a lot of things.